# How to add check mark on the checkbox after clicking the text/paragraph in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

*Greetings*, 1st time here, I need some help.

[ I just want to know if "**How can I add check mark on the checkbox after I press the text/paragraph in the html using the javascript"** ].

> Thank you in advance to all of you guys who answer and help me.

Comment: You can use css or JavaScript. Look at the :before or :after selector for CSS for the input checkbox, and the onclick event for JavaScript on the element. You probably want to toggle the checked attribute for the input element with the onclick event and have in CSS: input[type=checkbox]:checked::after { content: "checkmark" }

Comment: It's ok now, Thank you so much for your help bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. The simplest of which is using a `<label>`, like `<label><input type='checkbox' /> Click this text inside a label </label>`

```js
document.querySelector('.para').addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.querySelector('.check').checked = !document.querySelector('.check').checked
})
```

```css
.spacer {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<label><input type='checkbox' /> Click this text inside a label </label> 
<p>Or you can use javascript, as in</p>
<div>
  <label><input type='checkbox' class='check'/> I read this </label>
  <div class='spacer'></div>
  <p class='para'>Click on the text down here </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it <3